# Falha ao usar a biblioteca Retrofit no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit

Seguindo o tutorial abaixo,

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

que trata do uso da **biblioteca Retrofit**,  para testes, criei:

Uma **Activity** que chamei de **retrofit** e um **BUTTON** nela

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.Clientes;
import carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes.ClientesI;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class retrofit extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.retrofit);
        Button btnRf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRf);
        btnRf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View view) {
             ClientesI clientes = ClientesI.retrofit.create(ClientesI.class);
             final Call<Clientes> call = clientes.getClientes();
             call.enqueue(new Callback<Clientes>() {
                 @Override
                 public void onResponse(Call<Clientes> call, Response<Clientes> response) {
                     int code = response.code();
                     if (code == 200) {
                         Clientes cliente = response.body();
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Id do cliente: " + cliente.getIdClientesT(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Tipo do cliente: " + cliente.getTipo(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nome do cliente: " + cliente.getNome(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     } else {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Falha: " + String.valueOf(code), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                 }

                 @Override
                 public void onFailure(Call<Clientes> call, Throwable t) {
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }

             });
         }
     }
        );
    }

}
```

Uma **Interface ClientesI**

```
package carcleo.com.radiosingular.classes;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface ClientesI {

    @GET("/")

    Call<Clientes> getClientes();

    public static final Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

}
```

A **url** do **código** acima já entrega uma **string** em formato **JSON**,que está logo abaixo

```
{"clientes":[{"idClientesT":"1","tipo":"s","nome":"Carlos"},{"idClientesT":"2","tipo":"s","nome":"Rogério"}]}
```

Acontece que quando chega na linha

```
final Call<Clientes> call = clientes.getIdClientesT("");
```

está dando erro no console.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: carcleo.com.radiosingular, PID: 4015
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HTTP method annotation is required (e.g., @GET, @POST, etc.).
        for method ClientesI.getClientes
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:174)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)
        at $Proxy0.getClientes(Unknown Source)
        at carcleo.com.radiosingular.retrofit$1.onClick(retrofit.java:27)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5640)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22455)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:888)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:778)
```

no método `OnResponse`, é feita uma referência `Call<Clientes>`

```
 public void onResponse(Call<Clientes> call, Response<Clientes> response) {
```

E parece que é feita uma busca e nada é retornado. Pois busca por um parâmetro na `url` que não existe.

Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando errado a anotação da biblioteca. Na verdade você não está nem usando ela.

O erro é o seguinte:

> @Path can only be used with relative url on @GET

Primeiro você precisa entender o que cada um faz:

---

**@GET**

É uma anotação que adiciona à URL base novos valores.

**@Path**

É uma anotação que faz substituição de parâmetros do `@GET` para que o mesmo envie valores dinamicamente.

---

Só que o parâmentro do `@GET` está vazio. Logo, não há o que substituir.

Veja, a sua URL base é essa:

```
baseUrl("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php/")
```

Vamos supor que você realmente precise enviar uma string para a sua API. Logo, seria algo assim:

```
@GET("/{cliente}") // <-- adiciona parâmetro do cliente
Call<Clientes> getIdClientesT(@Path("cliente") String cliente); // <-- substitui parâmetro pelo nome
```

Agora a sua URL mudaria para, por exemplo, isto:

```
http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/clientest.php/Carlos
```

**Uma solução**

Do jeito que está sua URL irá dar problema de qualquer jeito. Fiz uns testes, e acho que seria interessante você passar esse `clientest.php` como parâmetro da url. Eu não sei aonde você cria o Objeto Cliente mas você pode fazer algo assim:

**Interface**

```
 @GET("{url}")
 Call<List<Clientes>> getIdClientesT(@Path("url") String url);
```

**Clientes**

Na classe Clientes você cria um atributo final estático assim:

```
static final String url = "clientest.php";
```

**Activity**

```
 final Call<List<Clientes>> call = clientes.getIdClientesT(Clientes.url);
```

E altere a URL base para:

```
 baseUrl("http://hotplateprensas.com.br/ws/");
```

Provavelmente isso resolverá o problema!

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87211/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei-coelho-falha-ao-usar-a-biblioteca-retrofit-no-and) (e pode prosseguir normalmente lá, basta clicar no link)